# Error "URL <File URL> does not exist" when trying to see modifications in log window

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a branch called #1234. This branch was merged into APPROVE (the source of that branch).
Now, I want to merge from APPROVE into FINAL, but only some files get merged.

I have about 5 added files and another 6 modified, and it only merges about 5 overall.

Now, if I open the APPROVE log window, select the merge revision of branch #1234, and try to double-click one of the files (one that didn't get merged) it shows an error:

"URL [URL to file in server] doesn't exist.

The file is present in my local dir (no remove ops in the log) and it is present in the server.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, there were unresolved conflicts and it wouldn't advance until these were resolved. After resolving them and redoing the merge, everything worked.